# What do gun opponents in the US say regarding the balance between security and the freedom to own guns?

Tags: united-states, guns

Right-wing gun activists in America are constantly talking about how banning guns [is against the 2nd amendment](https://www.realclearpolitics.com/video/2017/10/04/ben_shapiro_to_jimmy_kimmel_to_say_2nd_amendment_doesnt_cover_military-grade_weapons_is_like_saying_1st_amendment_doesnt_cover_tv.html) and how America [needs even more guns](http://www.breitbart.com/big-government/2017/09/28/national-reciprocity-picks-212th-house-sponsor/) to help people defend themselves in case of an armed attack. The underlying logic seems to be that owning guns is a natural freedom of all US citizens and tolerating mass shootings is a necessary evil in sustaining those freedoms.

So what do gun opponents say regarding this argument? Aren't mass shooting simply an unfortunate price to pay for extra freedoms in your society? For example many left-wing activists oppose increased surveillance by the state against domestic and international targets, arguing that increased security from potentially uncovered crime plots is not worth the loss of freedom to communicate in private.

Comment: As an aside, the argument against airport security is that it *doesn't* increase security (hence the term security theater), while it *does* restrict freedoms. The argument for gun control is that it *would* increase security.

Comment: @tim post updated. better now?

Comment: Yes, I think so. (the example is again not great though, as proponents of drug legalization don't really argue that addiction and health problems are a price to pay (it's at least not an argument I have heard before), but that people will do drugs either way, and legalization will make it easier for people to get help with addiction and legalization will make safer use easier, which will reduce health problems; I don't think that you need an example, but something like security vs privacy might be more fitting)

Comment: @tim yes, that's much better! Fixed

Comment: Do gun-freedom proponents actually believe that owning a gun is a **natural** right? As opposed to the **natural** right of self-defense, the right of gun ownership seems to be conferred only by the legal mechanism of the 2nd amendment.

Comment: Everything has a price. More security/surveillance = less freedoms. The gun control proponents are (at this time) wanting a ban on assault rifles which have been used for countless mass shootings. No one is talking about a complete ban on ALL guns (goes against 2nd amendment) and would struck down by Supreme Court.

Comment: One nitpick...effective self defense is a natural right of ALL humans, not just Americans. This right can only be *surrendered* to authourity. An authourity cannot *grant* this right to the people, it can only cease suppression of it.

Answer (score 4):

One rebuttal to your argument would be that introducing a firearm into a situation, even if with good intentions, has a greater likelihood of ending poorly if the individual wielding it is not trained, sober, and fully aware of the situation.

It is easy for me to imagine a scenario where well-meaning civilians get struck down by other well-meaning civilians or police during the chaos of a mass shooting. Caleb Keeter, a member of one of the bands that was performing in Las Vegas, [noted as much](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/arts-and-entertainment/wp/2017/10/02/i-cannot-express-how-wrong-i-was-country-guitarist-changes-mind-on-gun-control-after-vegas/?utm_term=.86fdd9649349) when he described why he has changed his views on the 2nd Amendment:

> We actually have members of our crew with [Concealed Handgun Licenses], and legal firearms on the bus. They were useless. We couldn’t touch them for fear police might think we were part of the massacre and shoot us.

Police response to a mass shooting could easily be hampered if they focus on the wrong individuals, and in situations where engagements span minutes opponents of your argument feel that the best response force are not random citizens from a crowd but trained professionals who have clear communication protocols.

I think what you're asking is what is the point that an individual's freedom ends, and, thanks to some fast talkers from long ago I would say the answer is "[where my nose begins](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/10/15/liberty-fist-nose/)." Not one of our basic rights comes unhindered without restrictions, not [free speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shouting_fire_in_a_crowded_theater), not [property rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_and_seizure), and *some barrier* to weapon ownership are not without precedent, unless of course you would also want to argue that ex-felons or perhaps even suspected terrorists are being denied their 2nd amendment rights, or how you can satisfy any other individual that you personally can think of who, in your opinion, shouldn't be allowed to carry a weapon for whatever reason (e.g. lack of training, mental health, *any reason*).

Comment: Those are all good points but your answer doesn't talk about the balance between freedom and security.

Comment: @JonathanReez Your question presents a false dilemma; _you_ having a gun does absolutely nothing for my security because _I don't know you_. You having a gun may just as easily _increase_ the likelihood of me getting injured as someone tries to shoot at you or as you try to shoot at someone else.

Comment: @JonathanReez Think back to all of the people you have ever met in your life, and imagine every single one of them are with you in Las Vegas at the show, and armed. Can you think of anyone that you may be saying to yourself, you know, I'd much rather they _not_ be carrying a weapon? Now imagine most of them have drank some random amount of alcohol. Do you still think it would be a good idea if they all had guns?

Comment: No no no. My argument is that being free to own guns is making America more free at the expense of being *less* secure. Just like destroying all surveillance programs might potentially make law enforcement work more difficult.

Comment: @JonathanReez And that is a valid argument, up to a point. We allow qualified, trained professionals to monitor for threats and thereby sacrifice some privacy. I don't allow you to, though, because I don't trust you with the responsibility of keeping my private information private.

Comment: @JonathanReez I have added another paragraph that I think ties the argument back to your question a bit better.

Comment: @JeffLambert Remember that you should be answering a question, not presenting a rebuttal to an argument. If the question is posed in such a way that to respond to it requires a rebuttal, then just comment/downvote/flag.